# Use file's contents in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, hash

My "information" file includes following hash.

```
student_balances = {"Jane Doe"=>1000, "Jim Doe"=>6200, "John Newman"=>73282, "Leonard Smith"=>3992, "Loe Newton"=>5643, "Eric"=>34234}
```

I want to import this "information" file into my main program and use its contents right away.

```
file_location = "Ruby/account.rb" 

f = File.open(file_location, "r+") 

student_balances.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} : #{value}"
end
```

I can't figure out how.

Comment: You are not using `f` anywhere ... Not understating your code..

Comment: I use `f`later on. My point is that I would like to import the hash from `account.rb` and use it directly.

Comment: Does your file contain only that single hash ?

Comment: Yes, stored as a hash in the variable `student_balances`.

Comment: Do you really need that `student_balances` variable in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to store the data in another format like YAML. It is more readable and easier to write:

```
# in balances.yml
"Jane Doe": 1000
"Jim Doe": 6200
"John Newman": 73282
"Leonard Smith": 3992
"Loe Newton": 5643
"Eric": 34234
```

Read the file with:

```
require 'yaml'
balances = YAML.load_file('balances.yml')
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for :) Why does it import directly as a hash?

Comment: Read this page (http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) about the syntax and the format of YAML files. It also support writing files, for example after you changed the balances: `File.open('new_balances.yml', 'w') { |f| f.write balances.to_yaml }`

Answer (score 0):

When the input files contains the following string and you will like
to import the string in a ruby variable you first have to evaluate the
string. Then you can use the variables as an array

```
student_balances = nil
DATA.readline.each do | line |
  eval line
  puts student_balances
end

__END__
student_balances = {"Jane Doe"=>1000, "Jim Doe"=>6200, "John Newman"=>73282, "Leonard Smith"=>3992, "Loe Newton"=>5643, "Eric"=>34234}
```

Comment: Using eval like that is really risky.

Comment: @robertodecurnex: that's very true. but that may answers the question?

Comment: @Monk_Code depends on the used ruby.